# How to reload windows form without closing it using VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net

Can you please tell me how I can reload a windows form without closing it using VB.NET?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Put all your initialization code into a method and not the constructor or the Form.Load event and just call that method. This can also include the designer-generated InitializeComponent() method which sets up all controls on the form. You should remove all controls on the form as your first action in that method, though.

Answer (score 12):

I know that it is late, but useful

```
Me.Controls.Clear() 'removes all the controls on the form
InitializeComponent() 'load all the controls again
Form1_Load(e, e) 'Load everything in your form, load event again
```

Comment: It's actually working. Putting all the startup codes in a method does not works to me. I was adding and removing lots of dynamic controls in a loop but `InitializeComponent` did the job.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot do that.

Why do you want to reload a form? Do you want to clear all input controls or something like that? The simplest solution might be to just do the clearing by hand.

**Alternatively**, you can put all your controls into a user control container. Then just instantiate that user control on your form. If you want to reload your form content, you now just need to remove and re-instantiate the user control.

Answer (score 5):

```
Application.Restart()
```

Shuts down the application and immediately opens a new instance.

Comment: A form not a whole application!

Comment: Don't know who voted this guy down but it's the cleanest answer. May not be a form refresh like AltF4 said but I don't think there is a clean way of reloading the form. The trick of clearing, initializing and running the load event won't work for everyone. More likely then not using Me.ControlsClear() is going to leave alot of resources open which is going to cause access violation issues upon "refresh". Clean restart is the only way to do it without being sloppy. +1

Comment: I just commented out a cumbersome block of code and replaced it with this. Much better!

Answer (score 2):

try using  `Me.Refresh()` it worked with me

Comment: You probably had a Refresh sub already defined for that to work.

Comment: Nope, Refresh is an option.

Answer (score 1):

```
Me.Controls.Clear() 'removes all the controls on the form
InitializeComponent() 'load all the controls again
main_Load(e, e)
MsgBox("Thank you for sending report", vbInformation, "")
Refresh()
```

Answer (score 0):

I know. I'm late to the party. But, maybe it works for who need it.

If you shows a form from other form with `.ShowDialog` the code after this call will be executed when the form that has been showed is closed. Example:

```
Private Sub button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles button1.Click
    Dim form2 As New Form2
    form2.ShowDialog
    UpdateThisForm()
End Sub
```

Then it's not necessary update the form from the other form (Form2).

Answer (score 0):

Execute the following line:
Form_Load(sender, e)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).